# PyQt4 StackedLayout does not show other layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

When I try to change layout using StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex() it skips the line and proceeds to the next line. The layout is not appearing.

mainqt.py

```
def checkQR(self, code):
    id = str(int(code))
    query.execute( "SELECT d.generic_name, d.strenght, m.quantity FROM medications m INNER JOIN drugs d ON m.drug_id=d.drug_id WHERE m.prescription_id = " + id)
    self.count = query.rowcount
    if query.rowcount > 0: 
        self.table.setRowCount(self.count)
        ct=0
        for row in query.fetchall():
            print(row[2])
            self.table.setItem(ct,0, QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
            self.table.setItem(ct,1, QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
            ct+=1
        self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(1) # Does not show layout 1
        if self.authenticate():
            self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(2) # Layout 2 appears
    else:
        self.scan_qr()

def authenticate(self):
    self.err_count = 0
    self.fp = fingerprint.fingerprint()
    self.OK = False
    while self.err_count<3:
        self.auth = self.fp.sensor() # waits for user fingerprint, returns 200 if in database
        if self.auth == 200:
            self.OK = True
            break
        else:
            self.err_count += 1

    if self.err_count==3:
        self.scan_qr
        self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    return self.OK
```

Comment: what value does self.authenticate() have? think that evaluating that if it takes very little time so changing the setCurrentIndex from 1 to 2 is instantaneous so you will not see that transition.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have included the authenticate().
self.auth = self.fp.sensor() waits for user fingerprint and returns 200 if the fingerprint is in database.